# Codeigniter SQL Server [You have specified an invalid database connection group (default) in your config/database.php file.]

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, continuous-integration

Please help me, i have some problem when i set `$config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE;`,
the message error is

> "You have specified an invalid database connection group (default) in
>   your config/database.php file."

But if i turn to `'False' (authentication)`, the connection is normal.
Btw, i use SQL Server connection

Answer (score 0):

problem solved
i was change

$active_group = 'dbsqlsrv';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['dbsqlsrv'] = array(
...
);

to

$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
...
);

Comment: this is probably not the best solution - the rest controller uses as database_group the `default` group. You could change it in your `rest.php` in the `application/config/` directory. There is an option called `rest_database_group`. in your case it would be `$config['rest_database_group'] = 'dbsqlsrv';`